How do I "negatively indent" one line of a list?
Suppose we have the following code:
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in,top=3cm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=4\parindent]
\item\label{crit:100} hgnl;fg
\item\label{crit:200} srgjl;
\newline
\textbf{This line}
\item\label{crit:300} klylrt
\item\label{crit:400} srglks
\item\label{crit:500} a;flke
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


I want the indentation of this line to be negative to that of the other lines.
Question: How do we "negatively indent" this line seperately from the other lines?
Edit: Here is where I want this line to be indented (see the dot).

Note this line should not be  enumerated.

Are you searching for a negative horizontal space, e.g., \hspace*{-4em} or \hspace*{-4\parindent}  or something like this? But maybe this should be a kind of section. In this case I would end the first enumerate and start a new one with option resume after the heading (see the enumitem manual section 3.4 for more information about series).

@cabohah I assume that is what I want....Is it possible to answer the question so I can check?

If I'd knew whether you are really searching for a negative indent or for a kind of heading and continuing an enumerate after the headings … But I don't know, so I don't know what to answer.

Negative horizontal spaces at the beginning of a line can be added using \hspace*{…}:
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in,top=3cm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=4\parindent]
\item\label{crit:100} hgnl;fg
\item\label{crit:200} srgjl;
\newline
\hspace*{-4\parindent}\textbf{This line}
\item\label{crit:300} klylrt
\item\label{crit:400} srglks
\item\label{crit:500} a;flke
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


But for me it looks like this is a kind of XY problem and you want a kind of heading and continue the enumeration after it:
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1in,top=3cm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\begin{document}
\section{Example}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=4\parindent]
\item\label{crit:100} hgnl;fg
\item\label{crit:200} srgjl;
\end{enumerate}
\subsection*{This line}% Just one example for a heading, maybe you want another level or a new kind of heading/list breaker.
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]% resume the enumeration with the same settings
\item\label{crit:300} klylrt
\item\label{crit:400} srglks
\item\label{crit:500} a;flke
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}



The first one answers my question.

@Arbuja But there must be a reason why you want a bold, shifted to the left line in a list. This is certainly not a completely normal request. Unfortunately, the semantics of the whole thing are not clear from your question. That's why I simply doubt a little that the \hspace* solution is the best option.
